# C++: possible bug in gcc optimization

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, optimization

I have got `gcc` version `8.2.1`.

In the following code I expect the compiler not to generate any code between two `mfence` instructions in the method `CheckAndPrint()`.

Indeed, it does the good job if I call `PrintGood<false>()` method and no code is generated. But if I out-comment `PrintBad<false>()` or even simple `return` the compiler generates a code for the `if`-expression `if (t.j > 0)`.

In all three cases there should be no reason to generate any code, especially for the costly branching.

The code below is compiled as:

`g++ -std=c++11 -Ofast optimization_problem.cc -o optimization_problem`

Tried to reach gcc bugzilla directly but had issues creating an account there.

Is there a good reason why the compiler managed to optimize the code in one case but non in the other two?

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Data {
  int i;
  int j;
};

template <typename Dummy>
class Test {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  void CheckAndPrint(const T &t);

 protected:
  template <bool print, typename T>
  inline void PrintGood(const std::string &prefix, const T &t);

  template <bool print, typename T>
  inline void PrintBad(const std::string &prefix, const std::string  &postfix, const T &t);
};

template <typename Dummy>
template <typename T>
inline void Test<Dummy>::CheckAndPrint(const T &t) {
  asm volatile ("mfence" ::: "memory");
  if (t.j > 0) {
    //return;
    //PrintBad<false>("<", ">", t);
    PrintGood<false>("<", t);
  }
  asm volatile ("mfence" ::: "memory");
}

template <typename Dummy>
template <bool print, typename T>
inline void Test<Dummy>::PrintGood(const std::string &prefix, const T &t) {
  if (print)
    std::cout << prefix << t.i << t.j << std::endl;
}

template <typename Dummy>
template <bool print, typename T>
inline void Test<Dummy>::PrintBad(const std::string &prefix, const std::string &postfix, const T &t) {
  if (print)
    std::cout << prefix << t.i << t.j << postfix << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  Data data;
  std::cin >> data.i;
  std::cin >> data.j;

  Test<int> t;
  t.CheckAndPrint(data);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No bug here. Actualy the fact the compiler generates the `if` when there is a return statement is perfectly understandable. For the compiler the content of asm statement generate observable behavior. When this is PrintBad, the compiler just miss an optimization opportunity.

Comment: is the `template <typename Dummy>` of any relevance? Do you get the same when you remove that?

Comment: Oops, I haven't completed my home work to the full extend. I was simplifying the code but forgot to double check the template influence. Indeed, looks like template is no relevance here. I can see the same behavior if the class `Test` is non-template.